# KMZ bbox to GPKG

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, kmz

Using OGR/GDAL programs, I would need to get the BBOX out of a KMZ file and import this BBOX into a GPKG. I can convert my KMZ into a GPKG using ogr2ogr, however I don't need to import all my KMZ layers but only the overall KMZ bounding box.

Comment: a gepackage sounds like over kill for a bounding box, usually 4 coordinates is sufficent

Answer (score 1):

GDAL utilities tend to work layer by layer. Therefore the first step would be to read the layer list with Python or as here with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo samples.kml
INFO: Open of `samples.kml'
      using driver `LIBKML' successful.
1: Placemarks
2: Styles and Markup
3: Highlighted Icon
4: Ground Overlays
5: Screen Overlays
6: Paths
7: Polygons
8: Google Campus
9: Extruded Polygon
10: Absolute and Relative
```

It is possible to query the BBOX of a single layer with the OGR SQLite dialect

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select Extent(geometry) from placemarks" samples.kml
...
  POLYGON ((-122.085766700618 37.4215692786755,-122.082203542568 37.4215692786755,-122.082203542568 37.4222899014025,-122.085766700618 37.4222899014025,-122.085766700618 37.4215692786755))
```

Now it is logically simple to enhance the SQL so that it gets a global extent of the layerwise extents, but the SQL gets somewhat long and not so clear to read. Here an example for two layers:

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select Extent(g) from (select Extent(geometry) as g from placemarks UNION select Extent(geometry) as g from paths);" samples.kml
...
POLYGON ((-122.085766700618 36.0795495214565,-112.080622229595 36.0795495214565,-112.080622229595 37.4222899014025,-122.085766700618 37.4222899014025,-122.085766700618 36.0795495214565));
```

By adding all the layer into the inner SQL it is finally possible to get the global extent of the whole KML file. The same query works with ogr2ogr and the global extent polygon can be saved into GeoPackage.

Myself I feel that my solution looks complicated. Perhaps I would just read the ogrinfo of all the layers with the `-al` option and then find the min/max coordinates from the rather short list.

```
ogrinfo samples.kml -al -so |find "Extent"
Extent: (-122.085767, 37.421569) - (-122.082204, 37.422290)
Extent: (-122.085655, 37.422431) - (-122.085655, 37.422431)
Extent: (-122.085655, 37.422431) - (-122.085655, 37.422431)
Extent: (14.601284, 37.465434) - (15.358327, 37.919042)
Extent: (-112.269527, 36.079550) - (-112.080622, 36.106779)
Extent: (-122.086016, 36.145318) - (-77.053155, 38.872910)
Extent: (-122.086016, 37.421293) - (-122.082850, 37.422818)
Extent: (-77.058441, 38.868758) - (-77.053155, 38.872910)
Extent: (-112.339659, 36.145318) - (-112.331131, 36.151401)
```

Comment: thanks that helps a lot, I managed to get the overall bbox, now I guess I need to put that into a geojson and convert to GPKG